# Troubleshooting @ParamConverter Issue in Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, query-builder, symfony6, symfony-routing

When calling a method in my controller, I encounter an issue with the `@ParamConverter` annotation in Symfony. The specific error I am facing is: `App\Entity\Recipe` object not found by the `@ParamConverter` annotation.'

I have a `findPublicRecipe()` method in my `RecipeRepository`. This method is supposed to fetch public recipes based on an optional parameter, `$nbRecipes`. Here is the method in question.

```
    function findPublicRecipe(?int $nbRecipes): array
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->where('r.isPublic = 1')
            ->orderBy('r.createdAt', 'DESC');

        if ($nbRecipes !== 0 && $nbRecipes !== null) {
            $queryBuilder->setMaxResults($nbRecipes);
        }

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

I'm calling this `findPublicRecipe()` method in my controller without using the `@ParamConverter` annotation. Here's the code from my controller:

```
    #[Route('/recipe/public', name: 'recipe.index.public', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function indexPublic(
        RecipeRepository $repository,
        Request $request,
        PaginatorInterface $paginator,
    ): Response {
        $recipes = $repository->findPublicRecipe(null);
        $recipes = $paginator->paginate(
            $recipes,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            10
        );

        return $this->render('pages/recipe/indexPublic.html.twig', [
            'recipes' => $recipes
        ]);
    }
```

Despite this, I'm still receiving the error mentioned above. I've checked that the `Recipe` entity is correctly imported into my controller and that the namespace path is correct. Additionally, I've verified that the `Recipe` entity is appropriately defined and the annotations are appropriate. Could anyone please help me understand why this error happens and how to fix it?